# Problema con destroy en laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo un metodo destroy en mi controlador y lo llamo desde una vista para borrar un registro, pero despues de confirmar que quiero borrar, la ventana se queda en blanco y no borra nada de nada y tampoco me redirige a otra vista.

El codigo del controlador es este:

```
    public function destroy($id)
    {
       Estudiante::findOrFail($id)->delete();
       return redirect('estudiante');
    }
```

Y en la vista lo llamo con el siguiente codigo:

```
<a href='{{ route('estudiante.destroy',$estudiante->id)}}' onclick="return confirm('¿Esta seguro de eliminar este Estudiante?')" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Eliminar">
    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

¿estoy haciendo algo mal o falta algo?

------------Solucionado-------------

Unos amigos en la universidad me dieron esta solucion y quiero compartirla para quien lo necesite

Solo era crear una nueva ruta en el archivo web.php

```
Route::get('estudiante/ocultar/{id}', 'EstudianteController@ocultar');
```

Luego crear una nueva funcion en el controlador al que va a apuntar la nueva ruta, y colocarle lo que estaba en la funcion destroy

```
public function ocultar($id)
{
    Estudiante::findOrFail($id)->delete();
    return redirect('estudiante');
}
```

Y por ultimo cambiar el link de la siguiente manera:

```
<a href='{{ url('estudiante/ocultar',$estudiante->id)}}' onclick="return confirm('¿Esta seguro de eliminar este Estudiante?')" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Eliminar">
     <i class="fas fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

Hecho todo esto funciona tranquilamente, muchas gracias a todos por los consejos

Comment: y cual es la ruta que usas para el destroy?

Comment: ¿cómo está definida la ruta? tal y como lo preguntaron antes

Comment: probaste con `return redirect()->route('estudiante');`

Comment: @user85131, ese es una mala forma de eliminar (en laravel) un dato, si bien funciona... no es la manera correcta de hacerlo(en laravel).

Comment: vas a eliminar registros desde un GET, osea cualquier persona te puede enviar ids como loco y eliminar todos los registros.

Answer (score 0):

Claro, al presionar sobre el link se va ir por el metodo GET, lo cual termina ejecutando el metodo SHOW de tu controloador

*¿Como solucionarlo?*

Lo mas facil es con un Formulario (FORM). Personalmente crearia un Modal donde estara mi formulario que llegara al metodo DESTROY

```
<div id="modal-emergent" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <form role='form' method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method('DELETE')
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h5 id="myModalLabel">Aviso</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <h5 style="text-align: center">Desea realmente eliminar el estudiante?</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancelar</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Si te fijas tengo un input oculto que contendra el ID, Para que me llegue el ID hasta ahi lo pongo con pequeño script, lo q haces es esperar que un boton eliminar haga click para colocar un paramentro que dicho boton tendra, que seria la ruta y lo ubicara en el action del FORM

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('a').click(function(event) {
        var data_url = $(this).attr('data-url');
        $('#modal-emergent form').attr('action', data_url);
    });
</script>
```

Mi boton eliminaria quedaria

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-emergent" data-url="{{route('reading.destroy', $reading->id)}}" class="btn btn-danger tip-top" title="Eliminar lectura">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: y hay alguna forma de cambiar el metodo get por el destroy en ese link? porque el boton esta en algo asi como una lista y no puedo modificar eso

Answer (score -1):

Para tu controlador esta bien añadir la siguiente función

```
public function destroy($id)
{
   Estudiante::findOrFail($id)->delete();
   return redirect('estudiante');
}
```

Lo que haremos sera enviar la id por medio de la ruta y se utilizara el método **POST** de la siguiente manera:

```
<form action="{{ route('estudiante.destroy', $estudiante->id) }}" class="d-inline" method="post">
```

Para lo siguiente usaremos su directiva especial **@method** donde especificaremos el metodo que queremos usara en este caso **DELETE**:

```
@method('DELETE')
```

Y para agregarle un poco de seguidad añadiremos un token de seguridad:

```
@csrf
```

Adjuntado todo con buton que de tipo enviar lo tendriamos de la siguiente manera:

```
<form action="{{ route('estudiante.destroy', $estudiante->id) }}" class="d-inline" method="post">
    @method('DELETE')
    @csrf
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger ">DELETE</button>
</form>
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Hola Kevin, aunque esta respuesta puede servir para resolver el problema expuesto en la pregunta, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido (aparte de que estaba en inglés). Las publicaciones que son básicamente código sin una explicación clara no suelen ser de ayuda para otros usuarios. Por favor, edita tu respuesta para añadir más detalles: ¿qué hace el código compartido? ¿cómo soluciona el problema? Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] donde encontrarás recomendaciones para mejorar tus publicaciones (y con ello ganarás tu primera medalla). Saludos.